# Allow remote ajax calls in an Android Webview + jquery mobile

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile, cross-domain, android-webview

I'm developing an javascript/HTML application with jquerymobile which makes ajax requests to a remote server. The application works fine on Chrome (only launching chrome with web security disabled) but when I embed it within the assets/ directory of an Android application (a simple webview) the remote ajax calls fail. Thus I guess it may be a cross domain issue. I'm aware that phonegap does not have this issue but I would like not to use phonegap if possible. So the question is: how do I disable cross domain protection in an Android webview application?

this is the Activity code:

```
public class Moby extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_moby);

    WebView mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); //get the WebView from the layout XML
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
        mbrowser.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    //mbrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mbrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); //set the HTML
    WebSettings settings = mbrowser.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}
```

}

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And I already set the jquerymobile cross domain parameters in my html pages:

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
 $.support.cors = true;
 $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;       
}); 
</script>
<script src="script/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough points to post this as a comment, however, please have a look at the following:

[ajax working on some Android devices, not in other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191338/ajax-working-on-some-android-devices-not-in-other)

Specifically, the following is required on Chrome based webViews:

webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

Edit: sorry, I just saw you're already doing this -- I tested this on my end and it seems to have solved my issue (was getting an access-control-allow-origin error when loading local links via ajax).

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
WebView web=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by overriding shouldInterceptRequest in my WebViewClient. I intercept the ajax call and do it in java. You have to do the same for POST methods

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
            Log.d("test", "onPageFinished");
            loadWebViewJavascriptBridgeJs(webView);
        }

        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView webview, WebResourceRequest webrequest)
        {
            Log.d("test", "shouldInterceptRequest");
           return this.handleRequest(webrequest.getUrl().toString());
        }

        @NonNull
        private WebResourceResponse handleRequest(@NonNull String urlString) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/json", "utf-8", inputStream);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
            catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I inticiate my webview, I instanciate my WebViewClient

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score -1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, do you have this line :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i gave to the application this uses-permission but the problem is still present