# ajax working on some Android devices, not in other

Tags: android, ajax, jquery-mobile

[LATER EDIT: As I found, the issue is related to Android version, not device type. So my code was perfect for Android till 4.0, not above. The fix is in the answer.]

I have wasted at least 2 days with this problem. I have few webpages packed as an Android application. And working perfectly on browser, and on my Android devices, including Galaxy Tab 2. But not on Nexus. I don't have it, so I kept making APK and a friend tested. The error was at AJAX. The same code work for me, do not work for him (and few others, I don't know their devices).

Below is the small test I use. As you can see, it's error free (this is my guess). Why is not working on all Android devices? I mention that I've compiled this code (the other refered files are here http://jumpshare.com/b/57O6tH) with Eclipse and also with Build.PhoneGap.com. Yet, the same result: the APK I get is working on some devices, not on others. Using *file:///android_asset/www/import.html* did not help me. The error is 404, as the file is not there. But it is!

Where is the mistake? It drives me crazy :). Why this code works fine in browser and as APK on my Galaxy Tab 2 (and on Samsung Gio), but not on Nexus (and other devices)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>   
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
        $("#buton").bind('click',function(){
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
            $.ajax({
                url:'import.html',
                datatype:'html',
                type: 'GET',
                success:function(html){
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    $("#result").html(html);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $("#result").html("ERRORS:"+errorThrown+"<hr>"+textStatus+"<hr>"+JSON.stringify(jqXHR))
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                    alert('Not working!!!');
                }
            })
        });
    });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <!-- Pagina de start -->
    <div data-role="page" id="start">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <button id="buton">AJAX!</button>
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found what I needed. Android 4.1 and 4.2 introduce this new method: getAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs

Since it's not working on API below 16 the solution needs some few more lines, to assure that this inexistent method do not cause errors in previous API.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        fixNewAndroid(webView);
    }
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

@TargetApi(16)
protected void fixNewAndroid(WebView webView) {
    try {
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what return your ajax GET? It is return DOM Document !
And you trying to set for your #result html the Document! 
If you take a look on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ you can see that your success function have 3 parameters :

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}
```

Now you are able to choice how to get your html and display it into `$("#result")`.

```
$("#result").html(jqXHR.responseText);
```