# How to disable web-security in JavaFx WebView?

Tags: web, javafx, cross-domain-policy

I am writing a JavaFx application and using WebView to load HTML. The JavaScript makes cross-domain calls. Dan you help to disable the web-security in JavaFx to make cross-domain calls possible?

Comment: You may want to check out this Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26101299/5250273

Comment: I am in development mode, where I don't have CORS enabled. Is there any option available?